# convert from float* to vector<float >

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I have a function 
`float * pointwise_search(vector<float > &P,vector<float > &Q,float* n, int len )`.

I want matlab call it so I need to write a mexFunction.

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) 
{ 
    if (nrhs != 4)
    {
        mexErrMsgTxt("Input is wrong!");
    }

    float *n = (float*) mxGetData(prhs[2]);
    int len = (int) mxGetScalar(prhs[3]);
    vector<float > Numbers= (vector<float >)mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
    vector<float > Q= (vector<float >)mxGetPr(prhs[1]);

    plhs[1] = pointwise_search(Numbers,Q,n,len );

  }
```

But I found that `vector<float > Numbers= (vector<float >)mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
        vector<float > Q= (vector<float >)mxGetPr(prhs[1]);` are wrong.

So I have to change `float * pointwise_search(vector<float > &P,vector<float > &Q,float* n, int len )` to `float * pointwise_search(float *P,float *Q,float* n, int len )`.

According to the answers, I rewrite as the following

```
 float * pointwise_search(float p,float *q,int num_thres, float n, int len ) 
{    vector<float> P{p, p + num_thres}; 
     vector<float> Q{q, q + num_thres}; 
     int size_of_threshold = P.size();
...
}
```

But there occur errors.

`pointwise_search.cpp(12) : error C2601: 'P' : local function definitions are illegal 
        pointwise_search.cpp(11): this line contains a '{' which has not yet been matched`

As the comment,I should change `vector<float> P{p, p + num_thres};` to `vector<float> P(p, p + num_thres);`. :）

Comment: Use the vector's iterator pair constructor with beginning and end pointers for the data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course you can not generally convert a pointer to a `vector`, they are different things. If however the pointer holds the address of the first element of a C-style array of known length, you can create a `vector` with the same contents as the array like:

```
std::vector<float> my_vector {arr, arr + arr_length};
```

where `arr` is said pointer and `arr_length` is the length of the array. You can then pass the `vector` to the function expecting `std::vector<float>&`.

Comment: ,Hi. I change to                                                float * pointwise_search(float *p,float *q,int num_thres, float* n, int len )
{
    vector<float> P{p, p + num_thres};
    vector<float> Q{q, q + num_thres};
 int size_of_threshold = P.size();...} But there occur error.

Comment: Do you compile in C++11 mode, e.g. `-std=c++11` for clang and gcc? Either do this (you should) or change the `{}` to `()`.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at e.g. [this `std::vector` constructor reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), you will see a constructor which takes two iterators (alternative 4 in the linked reference). This constructor can be used to construct a vector from another container, including arrays.

For example:

```
float* pf = new float[SOME_SIZE];
// Initialize the newly allocated memory

std::vector<float> vf{pf, pf + SOME_SIZE};
```